# FilterLink does not require a subscription to update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In Dan Abramov's egghead.io Redux course, Lecture 22, the video says that the `FilterLink` component needs to subscribe to the store explicitly (via a `forceUpdate`) in order for changes to be reflected in the component. Namely, after the `SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER` type action is dispatched upon clicking on a filter, the current filter (`state.visibilityFilter`) will change to the one clicked on.

My understanding from the lecture was that if we did not `subscribe` and do a `forceUpdate`, the formatting on the filters would not change because the information was not propagated to `FilterLink` form the store, and then on down to `Link`.

However, when I removed the lines with `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` in `FilterLink` component, the app worked fine and it seems the information was still being propagated even without explicitly forcing update from the store.

```
    class FilterLink extends Component {



      componentDidMount() {
        this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() =>
        this.forceUpdate()
      );
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      this.unsubscribe();
    }


    render() {

      const {
        filter,
        children,
      } = this.props;
      const state = store.getState();
      return (
        <Link
        active = {filter === state.visibilityFilter}
        onClick = {() => store.dispatch({
          type: 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER',
          filter: filter,
        })}


        >  {children}</Link>
    )
  }

  }
```

From the code below, we see that only the active link has a `<span>` (i.e. not underlined) and the non-active filters should appear with an underline below them.

```
  const Link = ({
    active,
    children,
    onClick,
  }) => {

if (active) {
  return (
    <span>
    {children}
    </span>
  )
}
else return (
  <a href='#' onClick = { e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      onClick()
    }
  }

  >{children}</a>
  )
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

My question is: The outcomes in the UI whether including or excluding the `componentDidMount`/`componentWillUnmount` lines were identical viz. the clicked-on filter will become span and not be underlined and the other two will become `<a>` and be underlined. This shows that even without an explicit subscription, the information from the store (`state.visibilityFilter` in this case) has been successfully passed down to `<Link>` component.

So does the subscription to the store and the forceUpdate in the `FilterLink` component achieve some sort of update that's important behind the scenes and is not apparent in the UI, or is this step purely optional? If there was an update not apparent in the UI, what was it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it still renders is because there was still a top level render `store.subscribe(render);` at this point in the code. Later in the video Dan will remove this top level render and have the classes handle lifecycle solely instead. The code change is [here](https://github.com/ee7klt/redux-abramov/commit/875ccfd6f9a418f0b62e0499af5e2f6ade97a1c3).